# Getting file with model field in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I am try to upaload a file with some other fields for model, but I can't binding file with those fields.
handling request.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       return "manageProduct";
    }
}
```

in model class with some other fields

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String code;

@NotBlank(message = "Product name can't be blank")
private String name;

@NotBlank(message = "Brand name can't be blank")
private String brand;

@NotBlank(message = "Description can't be blank.")
@Size(min = 10, max = 500, message = "Description shoud be contain 10 and 500 characters")
@JsonIgnore
private String description;

@Min(value = 1)
@Column(name = "unit_price")
private float unitPrice;

private int quantity;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "is_active")
@OrderBy("id ASC")
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "category_id")
@JsonIgnore
private int categoryId;

@Column(name = "supplier_id")
@JsonIgnore
private int supplierId;

private int purchases = 0;

private int views = 0;

@Transient
private MultipartFile file;

//getters and setters
}
```

form also enctype="multipart/form-data" and method is "post".
When try to upload file with others fields, then errors occurs. 
And I am using spring boot.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, sample file properties, and the full model?  Also, what's the specific question?

Comment: Updated my model class, mainly I can't bind with file and model class's fields.

Comment: Dont you want to actually store the file and associate back with your entity?  What good is it being transient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Data and JPA then [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) provides a solution to uploading and associating content with your entity.

As you are using Spring Boot it is easy to add.  Add the following dependencies:

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>     <!-- Or 0.1.0 for Spring Boot 2 -->
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>     <!-- Or 0.1.0 for Spring Boot 2 -->
   </dependency>
```

Add the following attributes to your `Product` entity so that content can be associated with it (this is in place of your Multipart file field):

> Product.java

```
@Entity
public class Product {

   ...existing fields...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;

   // no need for MultipartFile
```

Create a `ContentStore` (the equivalent of a JpaRepository for BLOBs):

> ProductContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="productsContent")
public interface ProductContentStore extends ContentStore<Product, String> {
}
```

When you run your application Spring Content will see the `ProductContentStore` interface and the `spring-content-jpa` dependency and inject an JPA implementation of this interface for you meaning that you don't have to write this yourself.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` dependency and add an @Controller implementation that forwards GET, PUT, POST and DELETE REST requests onto the `ProductContentStore` bean meaning that you don't have to write this controller either.   REST endpoints will be available at `/productsContent` so...

after creating your product and getting an ID, you can then:

`curl -X POST -F "image=@/some/local/path/product.jpg" /productsContent/{productId}`

to upload `product.jpg` and associate it with your product entity.  And:

`curl /productsContent/{productId}` will fetch it again.

Yes, this does imply that you need TWO requests to create a product and associate an image with it.  If you have valid reasons that justify why this needs to be one request and not two then raise an issue against Spring Content github repo and we can look into adding support this for you.

HTH

Comment: Tried your approach, and getting this error. Error processing condition on internal.org.springframework.content.jpa.boot.autoconfigure.JpaContentAutoConfiguration.databaseInitializer. I'm using mysql.

Comment: @Rashed are you using Spring Boot 1 or 2?  Can you raise an issue with the full stack trace on github (https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content/issues/new) pls?